# VMWare Authentication with Ansible module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Do I have to call hostname,Username and password field for all the individual task that I use with VMware module for Eg: if I call a task for Finding folder of VM and next for snapshot. Do we have an option to get authenticated and then parse token like we do with uri module ?

```
 - name: Find Guest's Folder using name     

   vmware_guest_find:

     hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"

     username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"

     password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"

     validate_certs: no

     name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

   delegate_to: localhost

   register: vm_folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [module_defaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html) to achieve what you want.

For instance:

```
- hosts: localhost
  module_defaults:
    vmware_guest_find:
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Find Guest's Folder using name     
    vmware_guest_find:
      validate_certs: no
      name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Comment: This works if I have to do anything with the module named "vmware_guest_find" anywhere in the playbook, But if I use differnt module like Create a Patching snapshot, or find guest details it does not work.

Comment: I guess you want to use [default groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html#module-defaults-groups). Unfortunately, the only supported groups are aws, azure, gcp, k8s and os so you have to make do with this until a group is added for vmware (if that ever happens).

Comment: Yeah, I read this one and this does not work with VMWare for now.